# Can TAR both record symbolic links and the files/directories they reference?

Tags: archive, tar, dereference

The Tar command has an -h flag to follow symbolic links *instead* of recording the symbolic links.  Is it possible to have *both* the symbolic links *and* what they point to in the archive?  Can this be done automatically in one run of the TAR command?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both the symbolic link and the directory/file it points to are inside the tar content.

For example, assume you have a file `work/mydir/myfile.txt` and a symbolic link `work/mylink` which points to that file (with relative path):

```
work:

drwxrwxr-x. 2 ...... ...... 4096 May 16 11:54 mydir
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ...... ......   16 May 16 11:54 mylink -> mydir/myfile.txt

work/mydir:

-rw-rw-r--. 1 ...... ......    0 May 16 11:54 myfile.txt
```

When you archive the `work` directory, both the symbolic link and the file are put inside the tar archive:

```
$ tar cvf work.tar work/
work/
work/mylink
work/mydir/
work/mydir/myfile.txt
```

When that tar archive will be extracted, the file and the symbolic link will be created in the target directory.

Comment: you can't use this if you want to add the files one by one -append- to the tar